# How to change image background position in CSS?

Tags: html, css, background

I have given the background position: fixed but the image not showing properly where i want to show them to the visitor. Is there anyway to change the position. I am using the blogger. Here is the code for the body tag

```
body {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/8x7qciX.jpg") no-repeat fixed center top #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
    font: 14px Arimo;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I want the car should be a bit top side, so i can cover the cover and track properly. Please help

Comment: try to set desired position with: background-position property.

Answer (score 0):

In css you could do something like:

```
body{
  background-position: 10px 20px;
}
```

instead of using center top.